# How do I display notice text if there is no list in that condition with append?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I have 4 tabs that user can click to view , if one of the tab list is empty I would like to display text such as `Nothing in the list yet!` If the list is not empty it will display all the list based on the if condition. I Have no problem in listing the list if is not empty. But I have problem in displaying the notice text `Nothing in the list yet!` if the list is empty.

[image]

It give 4 notice instead of 1. I only want to display one notice text. I believe it give 4 notice because in Type A have 3 listing available and in Type D Tab has 1 list.

below is what I have tried

```
    <div class="card-inner p-0">
                                            <table class="table table-orders">
                                                <thead class="tb-odr-head">
                                                    <tr class="tb-odr-item">
                                                        <th class="tb-odr-info">
                                                            <span class="text-center">#</span>
                                                        </th>
                                                        <th>
                                                            <span class="tb-odr-date d-none d-md-inline-block">Name</span>
                                                        </th>
                                                        <th class="tb-odr-amount">
                                                            <span class="tb-odr-status d-none d-md-inline-block"> Details</span>
                                                        </th>
                                                        <th class="tb-odr-action">&nbsp;</th>
                                                    </tr>
                                                </thead>
                                                <tbody class="tb-odr-body" id ="typeB">
                                                </tbody>
                                            </table>
                                        </div>
```

```
if (e.isd.id == '5') {
 //here
  }
  $("#typeB").append(`
                                <tr class="tb-odr">
                                    <td class="">${count++}</td>
                                    <td class="tb-odr-amount">
                                        <span class="tb-odr-total">
                                            <span class="amount">${e.name}</span><br>
                                        </span>
                                    </td>
                                    <td class="tb-odr">
                                        <span class="tb-odr-total">
                                            <p><small>${e.description}</small></p>
                                        </span>
                                    </td>
                                    
                                </tr>
                            `);
} else {
  $('#typeB').append(`<tr><td colspan="5"><div class="alert alert-danger text-center">Nothing in the list yet !</div></td></tr>`);
```

I tried to use this code in `//here` but it also not working

```
if ($("#typeB").length == '0' ) { $('#typeB').append(`<tr><td colspan="5"><div class="alert alert-danger text-center">Nothing in the list yet ! </div></td></tr>`);}
```

how to I fix this bug ?

Comment: Please provide us with a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), preferably in a working code snippet

Comment: If the red alert messages are being displayed from other types that are not relevant to the currently active tab, you can add an event that hides the other `$("#typeX")` when the tab for a type is selected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found my answer for this question

```
 <tbody class="tb-odr-body" id ="typeB">
  <tr id="noData"><td colspan="5"><div class="alert alert-danger text-center">Nothing in the list yet !</div></td></tr>
 </tbody>
```

I add this line in the `if (e.isd.id == '5') {}` and remove the else condition for this part.

```
if (e.isd.id == '5') {
  if ($("#typeB").length != 0 ) { $('#noData').remove();}
  }
```

So it will replace the text if there is data in the list.